# stop my idle remote desktop session form being logged out on windows server 2012 r2

Tags: session-timeout, windows-server-2012-r2, rdp

I'm running performance tests from a virtual windows 2012 r2 server. 
Tests take several hours to run, if my remote desktop session is disconnected or idle for more than ~30 minutes, then when I reconnect using mstsc.exe I login again and my existing session is either logged out at that point, or has expired during the intervening period.

I've used gpedit.msc On the server to set the Idle session timeout for remote desktop to never and restarted the server - But I'm still seeing the same behavior. Any ideas?

Note: 
I'm not an admin on the server, normal user with some extra permissions.

I've enabled the "Set time limit for disconnected sessions" and set it to "Never" under 'Computer Configuration' - Help suggests this is the dominant setting, and there's no overriding group policy.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same behavior with one of our 2012 R2 server.
After trying all hints finally, editing the registry on the server fixed this issue to me.
Login as local administrator into the 2012 R2 server.
Open registry.
Edit the values as below, save and restart the server.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Terminal Services
"MaxDisconnectionTime" set to 0
"MaxIdleTime" set to 0